# Creating a S3 Bucket and adding Task records in S3 from Salesforce trigger

Tags: triggers, amazon-s3, salesforce

I am attempting to add Task objects/records into AWS S3. I have installed Force.com for Amazon webservices.

I wrote the following trigger code

trigger S3Insert on Task (before insert) 
{
Task[] TaskList = Trigger.new;
 for(Task t :TaskList)
    {
            AWS_S3_ExampleController c = new AWS_S3_ExampleController();
            c.constructor();
            c.createBucket();
      }
}

But i get exception

Class.AWS_S3_ExampleController.createBucket: line 239, column 1
Trigger.S3Insert: line 9, column 1
05:36:00.224 (224038000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.FinalException: ApexPages.addMessages can only be called from a Visualforce page

Any pointers would be appreciated

edit: I see the debug log displaying "Callout from triggers are currently not supported". Any idea why?

Thank you
Sameer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have answer described @ 
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Callout-from-triggers-are-currently-not-supported/td-p/108871

Need to write the callout code in another Apex class which has @future annotation for the static void method making the callout. Call this method from the trigger.

regards
Sameer